# Pointer to Nothing When Using malloc?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

As far as I can tell I've followed the advice given by other users, but I still get a segfault when I try to return a pointer to an array.  The printf in main returns nothing, so I'm guessing that the pointer isn't to anything on the heap?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int * stringy(int length){
   int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*length);
   int i;
   for(i = 0; 1 < length; i++){
      ptr[i] = i;
   }
   return(ptr);
}

void main(int argc, char **argv){
   int strlen = 12;
   int *newptr = stringy(strlen);
   printf("%d\n",newptr[0]);
   free(newptr);
}
```

Comment: `1 < length` -- are you certain you didn't mean `i < length`?

Comment: `for(i = 0; 1 < length; i++)`??? No wonder it segfaults. Spellchecking your code is something you are supposed to be able to do yourself, without requesting worldwide help.

Comment: @AnT Making fun of people is not very constructive.

Comment: @SilverWingedSeraph: I think you are really stretching the concept of "making fun of people" beyond what's reasonable. Nobody is trying to "make fun" of anyone here.

Comment: @AnT An excessive number of questions marks along with exaggeration ('worldwide help') are really unnecessarily aggressive here, and are clearly meant to make this person feel bad.

Comment: @SilverWingedSeraph: I admit that there is a certain level of educational sarcasm involved there. But still perceiving it as me "making fun" of the OP is completely unjustified.

Comment: @SilverWingedSeraph  He's not making fun of me.  He's pointing out that I screwed up that for loop...

Comment: @Chib, As long as you don't feel that it's too aggressive, then it's fine :)

Comment: Using `strlen` as a variable name isn't precisely wrong, especially when you don't `#include <string.h>` and don't do any string manipulation, but it is not a good idea to use variable names that match any of functions defined in the standard library.  If nothing else, it is likely to lead to confusion if the code is modified and does need to do string manipulation.

Comment: Also note that `void main()` is only allowed by Microsoft C; see [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) for all the sordid details.

Comment: @SilverWingedSeraph That's really irrelevant.  You don't go onto an internet forum and expect hugs and feel-good words when you ask for help writing code.  I didn't spellcheck my code and he's telling me that I should spellcheck my code before posting a question on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Only on the Internet™: Someone becoming unhappy about me telling someone else to be nicer to them, after also answering their question. Anyway this is off topic, I'm going to stop responding.

Comment: It is good to have practise that after freeing up the memory always point pointer to NULL(Just to avoid dangling pointer). `newptr=NULL` In your case, program is terminating after `free()`. So the resources of your code will get also freed. No need to worry here. But in case of program which is executing continuously, there you will have to take care of dangling pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like there is a typo in your code. Instead of

```
for(i = 0; 1 < length; i++){
```

, it looks like you meant

```
for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
```

Comment: Do NOT cast the return of `malloc`. It is pointless. See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) for thorough explanation.

Comment: @Jarvis: You should not typecast malloc return value. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Yeah, I know that in `C`, `void *` is automatically and safely promoted to any other pointer type, but in order to compile it using `g++`, it's necessary to type-cast, and that's why I included this in my answer. But you read the answer of `Ron Burk` to the question `Do I cast the result of malloc?`, I think it makes more sense.

Comment: The question is tagged C, not C++.  These are different languages, as reflected in part by the fact that some good, idiomatic C code is invalid in C++.  That is not a basis for rejecting good coding practices, such as avoiding casting the return value of `malloc()`.  Use g++ only to compile C++ code.

Comment: Yes, you are right but I was just trying to share some extra info, and there is no harm in that. There was no need to downvote this answer, as long as my answer is answering the OP's question. @JohnBollinger

Comment: Giving bad advice along with the good makes this a bad answer.  A worse answer, in some ways, than if the whole thing were bad.

Comment: Can you make edits to this answer, and hopefully, then up-vote too ? :) @JohnBollinger

Comment: @Jarvis, I have edited the answer per your request, and lifted my downvote.  The remaining part of the answer is correct and useful, but it also underscores the fact that the question should have been closed, not answered.  With luck it may still be closed.

Comment: if you get errors about the cast then you're compiling it in C++ mode

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for null pointers; `malloc` returns `NULL` when it can't allocate the memory you requested, and that would cause the problem you're referring to. Also, you should cast your pointer to `int *`.

The actual problem, however, is that you have a typo; rather than `1 < length`, your for loop condition should read `i < length`. Your for loop runs forever.

Comment: I ditched that part of the code, just to see whether it would get rid of the error.  The for loop declaration was the issue though.

Comment: You should *not* cast the return value of `malloc()` in C, unless you are making the extraordinary effort required to code simultaneously in C and C++.  And that's tricky to do, and rarely worthwhile.